# Retrieve label HTML from node

Tags: javascript, thejit

I have a node of a SpaceTree graph (from the [JIT](http://philogb.github.io/jit/) library) and I'd like to modify the HTML of its label in a click listener. This would be trivial if I had a reference to the label object that is passed as a parameter to the `onPlaceLabel()` and `onCreateLabel()` functions, but I cannot find a way to get a reference. Is there an easy way of obtaining that reference from a node object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can get the the label of a node using

```
st.labels.getLabel(node.id)
```

Assuming `st` is the SpaceTree object and `node` is the node for which to get the label.